# Applying migrations and 'flight.objects.all()' result in an error

Tags: django, sqlite, migration

In my Django project I encounter errors when trying to apply migrations using `python manage.py migrate` and `flight.objects.all()`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey('airport', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="departure")
    destination = models.ForeignKey('airport', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="arrival")
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.origin} to {self.destination}"

class Airport(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} ({self.code})"
```

The `Flight` table had two character fields instead of foreign keys and I had stored a row in it, but later I decided to use `Airport` table as a foreign key in `Flight` table. However after I exited the shell and tried to run `python manage.py migrate` I got an error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'flights_flight' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: flights_flight.origin_id contains a value 'Kathmandu' that does not have a corresponding value in flights_airport.id.

It might be because of the previously stored data in `Flight` table so I tried to delete it, however I can't even view the contents of it. Whenever I try running `flight.object.all()` I get another error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: flights_flight.origin_id

What is the cause of these issues and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of your issue, it seems relevant that you had a table named `flights_flight` in your database. The issue is arising since `flights_flight` table references the table `flights_airport` via column `origin`. This column or field must contain the primary key for `airport` which is an `id` field (default if not overidden). Hence, the row in `flights_flight` table having `id=1` has the field `origin=Kathmandu` which is incorrect. Rather it should have the `primary key` for the table `flights_airport` having the `city=Kathmandu`. Hence, one solution would be to backup the `airport` table data and `flights` table data and truncate the table. After applying the migrations, restore the `airport` data and modify the `flights` data such that the `origin` column contains the primary key to the appropriate `airport` row.

Hope this solves your problem.